# staggered grid view in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

I am making a grid like instagram where every seventh element is of 2X1. The problem is i want to show a different widget at seventh index but my code splits the gridTile widget rather than showing a different widget.

**CODE:-**

```
return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    itemCount: gridTile.length,
    itemBuilder: (context,index)=>gridTile[index],
    staggeredTileBuilder: (index)=>StaggeredTile.count(
      1,(index%7==0)?2:1,
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change your itemBuilder line of code as follow instead of "yourWidget" please write widget name you want to return.

```
itemBuilder : (context, index) {
  return index % 7 == 0 ? yourWidget : gridTile[index];
},
```